# Git clone --recurse-submodules throws error on MacOs: Transmission type 'file' not allowed

Tags: git

I have a git remote repository on a network drive an try to clone this repository to a Mac Computer with:

```
git clone --rescurse-submodules /Volumes/path/to/repository.
```

The main repository is cloning fine but for all submodules I get a message like:

```
Transmission type 'file' not allowed
```

(original message in german is `Übertragungsart 'file' nicht erlaubt`).

The submodule folders stay empty.

The path to the submodules seems fine so I don't think it is a path related error.
The same operation on a Windows Machine is working fine.

Comment: Here’s the error message translation in Git source https://github.com/git/git/blob/eea7033409a0ed713c78437fc76486983d211e25/po/de.po#L21238

Comment: According to the translation file the error is "transport 'file' not allowed". Thank you that's very helpful. Suddenly I am no more alone with my problem.

Comment: `git config --global protocol.file.allow always` See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-protocolallow

Comment: Yes, thank you. In the mean time I found it my self. Shame on me that it was just a translation issue to get to the right solution.

Answer (score 18):

The [translation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/eea7033409a0ed713c78437fc76486983d211e25/po/de.po#L21237) of your error message is:

```
transport 'file' not allowed
```

To solve it, run:

```bash
git config --global protocol.file.allow always
git clone --recurse-submodules /Volumes/path/to/repository
```

or

```
git -c protocol.file.allow=always clone --recurse-submodules /Volumes/path/to/repository
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-protocolallow.

---

Thanks to [grg's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486167/git-clone-recurse-submodules-throws-error-on-macos-transmission-type-file-n#comment131488816_74486167) and [phd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486167/git-clone-recurse-submodules-throws-error-on-macos-transmission-type-file-n#comment131489911_74486167).

Comment: Note that this also fixes the same issue for submodule add: `git -c protocol.file.allow=always submodule add ../dir`

Comment: Note that this is potentially unsafe: https://github.blog/2022-10-18-git-security-vulnerabilities-announced/#fn-67904-1